# Scala: Want to implement the function to be called before each method of the same class(something like @before implementation))

Tags: scala

Is there a way to invoke a function by default before any other function in a class is called?

I do not want to use frameworks and want to implement in pure Scala.

What I wanted to do is have some function in a class which checks if a user has access to the called method when a method of the same class is called.

Comment: Pure solution would be grouping methods by their access requirements or passing user as an additional argument and injecting access verification service in constructor or sth and explicitly verify access rights. What you want would be doable using some macros or runtime reflection but I would ban such solution in a production code if I had anything to say about this.

Comment: What about putting that call on the constructor? Also, do you want to explain why do you ant to do that? What are you trying to model / solve? It is a pretty strange requirement.

Comment: Can it be done using custom annotations, so that a method is called in annotation class

Comment: I want to do something like @Before annotation in play framework

Comment: Putting in constructor means method will be called during Object creation but i want to call that particular method before every method call. @Lui

Comment: Ok, I get you want the function to be called before each method. But why? Also, the idea is that this will be used just for one class? Or for many? Or like an interface?

Comment: The idea is in a class i will be having multiple methods which are restricted based on a role. so i want to check that restriction in before method and return the control if that function is having the restricted access. so i want to control the call for method even before going to that method. @Luis

Comment: Can you please elaborate by seeing the question again, i have changed it.@Mateus

Comment: The best way to do something like this is forget about OOP. Think about all your methods as a big `Request => Response` function. And the authorisation as a function from one `Request => Response` to another `Request => Response` in other words, function composition. That is how **http4s** does it for example.

Answer (score 0):

This is done in a straightforward way with a private constructor, custom `apply` and companion object.

```
  case class Foo private (bar: Bar){
    def methYouWantToCall: Unit = ???
  }
  object Foo {
    def apply(bar: Bar): Foo = {
      val foo = new Foo(bar)
      foo.methYouWantToCall
      foo
    }
  }
```

Hence `methYouWantToCall` should be sideffecting function with `Unit` return type. 
As you use scala, there are plenty of means of avoiding such ones.

Comment: Please check the Question once again i have edited it

Comment: What does "a user has access to the called method" mean? That's security or permission or what?